# Function as unlabeled prop in JavaScript. What is this called, and how does it work?

Tags: javascript, function, properties, inline

I saw this code today, which does something I've never seen before.  It has an object which itself has an unlabeled property that is a function.

```
 emails = {
      type: EmailType,
      args: { id: { type: GraphQLID } },
      resolve(parentValue, args) {
         const query = `SELECT * FROM "emails" WHERE id=${args.id}`;
         return db.conn.one(query)
            .then(data => {
               return data;
            })
            .catch(err => {
               return 'The error is', err;
            });
        }
      }
   }
```

I'd like to know more about this, but I have no idea what the proper keyterm for this is, and searching "function as property js" only yields really obvious stuff (ie `{someProp: () => 42}`).

I'm certain that both:

A. If I knew the right key term, it would be really easy to learn more and

B. The only way to make this keyterm easier to find is to have something someone would actually search lead to it.  To that end, I'll include some extra SEO:

- object has function but not at prop
- function inlined in object
- function in object
- object has a function but it's not a prop
- no propname for function

Anyways:

**What is this called, and where can I find more information on it?**

EDIT: Got links to docs.  One thing to denote is the differences between

```
// these are the same, I think
const eg1 = { someFn() {} }
const eg2 = { someFn: function() {} }

// this is different in scope... I think
const someFn = () => {};
const eg3 = { someFn };
```

Comment: Don't think this is called anything - and what's an example of `data`? Is this run inside a Promise object? What does `emails` look like after all the asynchronous code is run?

Comment: It's just [method definition shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions#Description).

Comment: I'm talking about the resolve part.  Ignore the rest.  If it helps, imagine this object: `{ doThing() { alert() }`

Comment: It appears to act more like `{doThing: function(){}}` and less like `{doThing: () => void}`.  Making an edit to my question.

Comment: There is another difference. Try `new eg1.someFn` and then `new eg2.someFn`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [*Shorthand method name*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```
  { method() { /*...*/ } }
```

is equal to:

```
  { method: function() { /*...*/ } }
```